Cannot execute puppeteer from php
When I try to run a Puppeteer command from PHP using the exec function, I get this error:
Error: EACCES: permission denied, stat '/root/.config/puppeteer'

Do you know how to resolve this problem?
I tried to set the owner and the group of the folder /root/.config/puppeteer to www-data and set the chmod to 777 but this didn't work.
I also tried this:
process.env.PUPPETEER_DOWNLOAD_PATH = '/var/www/.chromium-browser-snapshots';
process.env.PUPPETEER_CONFIG = '/var/www/.puppeteer';
process.env.PUPPETEER_CACHE_DIR = '/var/www/.puppeteer';
process.env.PUPPETEER_USER_DATA_DIR = '/var/www/.puppeteer';


Please share a [mcve].

launching puppeteer from publicly accessible php file is probably going to take down your server. You know how much resources puppeteer uses, right?

I have the exact same error.. :/

Maybe it's because puppeteer cannot find the executable for chrome, when it is executed from PHP.
Add to your server code: (change executablePath where the chrome executable is at)
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: 'new',

  // must so it works from php's `shell_exec`
  executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe',

});


I tried this but I'm getting different error when using the php exec function:
Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
chrome_crashpad_handler: --database is required
Try 'chrome_crashpad_handler --help' for more information.
[677776:677776:0601/230813.466812:ERROR:socket.cc(120)] recvmsg: Connection reset by peer (104)

It works fine when executing the command from ssh

It finally worked by installing puppeteer@21 instead of the last version.
